# Turning off cp (copy) command's interactive mode (cp : overwrite ?)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, copy, ubuntu-9.04, cp

Does anyone know how I would turn off the interactive mode when using cp?

I am trying to copy a directory recursively into another and for each file that is getting overwritten I have to answer 'y'.

The command I am using is:

```
cp -r /usr/share/drupal-update/* /usr/share/drupal
```

But I get asked to confirm each overwrite:

```
cp: overwrite `./CHANGELOG.txt'? y  
cp: overwrite `./COPYRIGHT.txt'? y  
cp: overwrite `./INSTALL.mysql.txt'? y  
cp: overwrite `./INSTALL.pgsql.txt'? y  
...
```

I am using ubuntu server version jaunty.
Thanks!

Comment: Removing the alias is typically "unalias". It is also a bad idea to change the question, as the answers no longer makes sense.

Comment: I agree that it is a bad idea to change the question - but the question was never changed - I just added tags.

Comment: Personally I'm such a huge fan of *rsync* that I tend to use it even when copying files around locally. OK, not when I have only a simple copy operation ahead, but during larger transfers, yes. Why? Because rsync has great versatility when it comes to recursive transfers, dry runs, including/excluding, preserving various permissions, continuing interrupted operations and so on.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Execute:

```
alias cp
```

To see if `cp` has been aliased to `cp -i`

In that case run:

```
\cp -r /usr/share/drupal-update/* /usr/share/drupal
```

to ignore the alias

Comment: I would suggest finding where the alias was made and removing it... hopefully they put it in a local file. This hand holding is on my reasons for not using *buntu

Comment: This is an old thread, but Ive upgraded to Fedora 19, and this happened to. Someone defaulted an alias for cp

Comment: To use the original command, rather than the ailas, use `command cp ...`

Comment: You can also do an `unalias cp` in that case.

Answer (score 3):

cp -f will not ask for confirmation (that's force)
So do

```
cp -fr /usr/share/drupal-update/* /usr/share/drupal
```

Comment: cp -fr is still asking for confirmation :(

Comment: --remove-destination maybe?

Comment: --remove-destination can indeed help in that case. It's typically an access rights problem if it's needed.

Comment: cp -fr still asks for confirmation if it has an alias with interactive: "alias cp='/bin/cp -i'". You either need to unalias cp: "unalias cp" or you can run without the alias using \: "\cp -r /bla/ /foo/". See Duane's answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Yea the reason for `cp` command to be interactive because in many common shells by default copy comes with alias as `cp -i` this can be found by running command as follows :

> `alias cp`

output will be

`alias cp='cp -i'`

There are different ways to solve it. Solutions are :

**Solution 1.** Set alias for that session/permanently in the system or offload alias for cp command.

unset alias: *will remove alias for that command.*
`unalias cp`

or

resetting alias:

`alias cp='cp'`

the above command will set alias for `cp` to be just `cp` itself instead of `cp -i`. So you can run copy commands as many as you want  without interactive mode just for that terminal **session only**(temporary). To make that permanent you may reset alias in respective files say

```
Bash – ~/.bashrc
ZSH – ~/.zshrc
Fish – ~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

**Solution 2.** Run with `cp` command with a backslash `\` at the beginning of the copy command.

`\cp foo.log /tmp/`

This will effectively ignores the alias for the `cp` command just for that command only.

**Inference:**
Solution 1 is good to set it temporary or permanent if you intend to run lot of `cp` commands and you want to turn off the interactive mode.

Solution2 is good if you only have couple of `cp` commands only and don't want to reset the alias, this will be good.